# Really need some assistance, first programming project

Tags: c++

My formatting is really bad, and I'm sorry for that, but I'm still in the very early stages of learning C++. Anyway, no matter what I try, I always get an expected unqualified ID error on line 51. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! And no, the code is not finished, its due March 20th, just wanted to start on it early. And this is NOT how I wanted to format it, but this is how it was stated on the rubric. I'm brand new to functions, so yeah, any help would be awesome!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


int menu (int); //Menu prototype for 4 options

int main()
{
   const int numWidth = 4;
   int choice, pick;
   cout << "Welcome! Please select your choice by entering 1, 2, 3, or 4!" << endl;
   cout << "1:";
   cout << right << setw(numWidth) << " Enter the Grades" << endl;
   cout << "2:";
   cout << right << setw(numWidth) << " Display the Grades" << endl;
   cout << "3:";
   cout << right << setw(numWidth) << " Show overall Grade" << endl;
   cout << "4:";
   cout << right << setw(numWidth) << " Exit the program" << endl;
   cout << "Select your choice and press enter ";
   cin >> choice;
   pick = menu(choice);
   cout << pick;
   if (choice ==1)
  {

  cout << ". Please enter your grades.\n";
  }
float AssignmentGrade(float, float, float, float); // Assignment Grade Prototype
 {
    float asgnment1, asgnment2, asgnment3, asgnment4, total;
    cout << "First, enter your 4 assignment grades ";
    cin >> asgnment1 >> asgnment2 >> asgnment3 >> asgnment4;
    total = AssignmentGrade (asgnment1, asgnment2, asgnment3, asgnment4);
    cout << total;
    return 0;
 }
}

float AssignmentGrade (float num1, float num2, float num3, float num4)
{
    float asgnmentgrade;
    asgnmentgrade = num1*0.05 + num2*0.05 + num3*0.05 + num4*0.05;
    cout << "Total points, including weights, for assignment grade is ";
    return asgnmentgrade;
}

float LabTestGrade (float, float, float); // Right here, line 51, is where I get expected unqualified ID error before {
{
    float lab1, lab2, lab3, total;
    cout <<"Next, please enter your 3 lab test scores!";
    cin >> lab1 >> lab2 >> lab3;
    total = LabTestGrade (lab1, lab2, lab3);
    cout << total;
    return 0;
}

float LabTestGrade (float lab1, float lab2, float lab3)
{
    float LabGrade;
    LabGrade = lab1*0.10 + lab2*0.10 + lab3*0.10;
    cout << "Total points earned from lab tests is";
    return LabGrade;
}
int menu (int num)
{
   int option;
   option = num;
   cout <<"You have selected ";
   return option;
}
```

Comment: You wrongly placed `;` two characters before that comment. Same for `AssignmentGrade`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand? I thought to state prototypes you needed semicolons? Its really early in the morning but I can't sleep until this syntax error gets fixed haha

Comment: IDE will fix your sleeping issues.

Answer (score 1):

Delete unnecessary `;` in your 51st line: `float LabTestGrade (float, float, float);`

Dont forget that `;` is used for the end of a command. If you define a function, you don't use it. Look at th following model:

```
float function (float parameter) {
    command();
    command();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: There's the same syntax error in your 31th line.

Delete `;` again in `float AssignmentGrade(float, float, float, float);`

Comment: The semicolons are for the function prototypes, if I remove them, then I define the function twice, and another error occurs.

Comment: @TheDakmariolink No.

Comment: A function prototype has no body. It's defined like `float AssignmentGrade(float, float, float, float);`, but it has NO BODY.

Comment: But line 51 is not inside the body? Its separated from the rest of the code. Look I'm really noob at this...

Comment: Wait a minute... Think I just had an epiphany.

Comment: In 51th line there is again a function with `;` and the body. Delete that body and it should work.

Comment: Nope, I thought that moving the prototypes up at the top would fix it, but it only gave me a previously defined function error...

Answer (score 0):

You will find yourself running into a few other problems with this function, apart from the original unqualified ID that @Nichar answered.

At Line 50 you have:

```
float LabTestGrade (float, float, float) { // Function Code }
```

and at Line 60 you have:

```
float LabTestGrade (float lab1, float lab2, float lab3) { // Function Code }
```

This will cause a compile error as you are trying to define another function with the exact same name and parameters. (Redefinition error)

Although these functions may look slightly different as you have named the parameters of the second one (float lab1, float lab2, float lab3), to the compiler it will simply see two functions that are named the same and take in the same types as parameters.

That being said, you can delete the parameters in the first LabTestGrade() as they aren't actually being used inside its function.

```
float LabTestGrade() { // Function Code }
```

Finally, you are also going to want to swap around the order that these two functions are being defined. I suggest googling C++ Scope but basically the first LabTestGrade() is making a call to the second LabTestGrade(float lab1, lab2, lab3) like so.

```
total = LabTestGrade(lab1,lab2,lab3);
```

However, the second LabTestGrade hasn't been defined yet within your program so it will try to call the first LabTestGrade() again and give you an error because the first LabTestGrade() doesn't take in any parameters now and this line of code is trying to pass into it three floats into a function that takes in nothing.

Alternatively, you could just declare the functions above your main function like you had done for your menu function.

```
float LabTestGrade();
float LabTestGrade(float lab1, float lab2, float lab3);
int menu(int) // Menu prototype for 4 options
```

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me out! One thing I'm still terrible at, however, are using brackets in conjunction with if/else statements. My program just ends after I enter the first set of grades in, after the first function, the return assignment grades are outputted, then the program just ends.

Answer (score -1):

Hi even im a beginner but heres what i think -

First of all
The menu prototype in the beginning is incorrect . Prototypes should be exactly same as the function itself .
Correct prototype will be

```
int menu (int num);
```

In line 51 , in the parameter bracket, try writing the full name of the float types you r trying to get. Also remove the semicolon. Ex:-

```
float LabTestGrade (float a , float b , float c) { }
```

A similar mistake is made in the AssignmentGrade function which takes 4 floats.
Try writing the full name as parameters. Remove the semi colon.

Write the function prototypes separately in the beginning outside the main.
You have to create a separate prototype for every function you make and remember - prototypes should have the same name as the function. Just you need to replace the curly braces with a semi colon.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:- You can also try writing the functions outside main and then use prototypes in the beginning outside the main.

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me out! One thing I'm still terrible at, however, are using brackets in conjunction with if/else statements. My program just ends after I enter the first set of grades in, after the first function, the return assignment grades are outputted, then the program just ends.

Comment: You have written return 0 within the first function which means it will end the program once it finished executing that function. Your function is a float type hence it should return a float at the end not 0. return 0 terminates the program.

Comment: Also , i would like to suggest that you have a better look into functions . Functions r important and having a good understanding of them is a must. It will help you in the future.

Comment: @Mr.Momo Maybe you should have a look into functions, given that what you claim about the prototype is incorrect.

Comment: @juanchopanza What is incorrect? It was really just a suggestion. I said i'm a beginner too and i'm happy to know and correct my mistakes.

Comment: I was referring to this part: *"First of all The menu prototype in the beginning is incorrect ."* The prototype in OP's code is fine, there is no problem with it. I haven't checked the rest.

Comment: Oh ok you are right i guess. I haven't seen that kind of syntax before and never seen anyone used it. Thats something new i learnt.